# s3 file storage image issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, request, typeahead.js, head

I stored an image in s3 and in GET request(it is showing Content-Type as **image/jpeg**) or browser I'm able to see the image but when I try HEAD request to it is showing Content-Type as **application/xml**. As Head request is defaultly used to find the type of file what should I do to change the **Content-Type** in **S3**.

Comment: What is the HTTP status code of the `HEAD` response?  It seems very likely that it is `403 Forbidden`.  The `Content-Type` is only a side effect of the actual problem.  Is this using pre-signed URLs?

Comment: ya it is 403 forbidden and how to find whether it is a pre-signed URLs @Michael-sqlbot